# Keep WPF window on the current working monitor (in multiple-monitor setup)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, monitor

I'm developing an WPF application. In my application there will be a main window (System.Windows.Window) and on top of it I will be navigating between pages (System.Windows.Controls.Page). Whenever I'm navigating from one page to another page, I want it to be at the center of the current working monitor (multiple monitors will be available). I'm able to achieve the center positioning the main window using below code. **I will be calling the below code with current window's width and height whenever I'm navigating between pages (Ex: Login page -> Home page)**

```
public static void CenterWindowOnScreen(double width, double height)
{
    double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    double windowWidth = width;
    double windowHeight = height;
    App.Current.MainWindow.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
    App.Current.MainWindow.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
}
```

On the application launch, Main window is loaded with login page and positioned at the center of the primary monitor. Now I drag and drop the Main window to another (Secondary) monitor, and When I try to login, The Main window is automatically moved to the primary monitor. So now the Main Window is loaded with Home page, But the window is on the primary monitor. I want to keep the main window at the center of the current working monitor (In this case Secondary monitor).

Comment: I would advise not to have your window jump around on its own. As a user, I find this very unpleasant. If you are sure about that feature, or have no control over it, I'd suggest using `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight` and `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth`, which return the combined size of all screens.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position a window on multi-monitor displays in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338512/how-to-position-a-window-on-multi-monitor-displays-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

I just missed to add working Area's Left and Top coordinates. The below link helped me to center the WPF window on current working monitor with multiple monitors connected (with different DPI scales).
Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/68283497/6454203

Comment: Prefer mark as duplicate and/or close your question instead of giving another link. It's to prevent same question multiple times using same answer